# Scale video texture with mask over image texture background

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

Referencing this previous question [Scaling Video texture mixed with image texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68121521/scaling-video-texture-mixed-with-image-texture/68121778#68121778)

I have the webcam video texture partially scaling with a mask provided by bodypix data. However I can't figure out how to remove the white background produced from mixing the two. I'm not sure where the extra alpha is coming from.

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/danrossi303/q8gz5cun/10/

the fragment for this

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D background;
uniform sampler2D frame;
uniform sampler2D mask;

uniform float texWidth;
uniform float texHeight;


void main(void) {
vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(texWidth,texHeight);
vec2 frameuv = texCoord * vec2(texWidth, texHeight) / vec2(200.0, 200.0);

vec4 texel0 = texture2D(background, texCoord);
vec4 frameTex = texture2D(frame, frameuv.xy);
vec4 maskTex = texture2D(mask, frameuv.xy);

vec4 texel1 = vec4(frameTex.rgb, maskTex.a * 255.);

gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(background, texCoord), texel1, step(frameuv.x, 1.0) * step(frameuv.y, 1.0));
}
```

I need to position the scaled video to any corner of the canvas, and somehow provide a dynamic uniform to change the texture coord back to the viewport size. Currently it is hardcoded to 200, but should revert back.

Unscaled example with masked bodypix video over image.

https://jsfiddle.net/danrossi303/q8gz5cun/6/

Answer (score 0):

The alpha channel is in range [0.0, 1.0] (linke the color channels. Hence the multiplication with *255.* is obviously wrong:

<s>`vec4 texel1 = vec4(frameTex.rgb, maskTex.a * 255.);`</s>

```c
vec4 texel1 = vec4(frameTex.rgb, maskTex.a);
```

Mixing the textures will likely depend on the mask:

```c
gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(background, texCoord), texel1, 
    step(frameuv.x, 1.0) * step(frameuv.y, 1.0) * maskTex.a);
```