# Position scaled video texture over image texture background

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I have this working scaled masked video texture over an image texture background. However it is positioned in the bottom left corner. I tried some tricks multiplying the coords but it doesn't seem to make much difference. I'll probably have to make alot of the values changeable uniforms but hardcoded ok for now.

What values can be used to change the video texture coords to display in the top right or bottom right corner ?

The video is a webcam stream with bodypix data providing the mask.

The alpha in mix is from bodypix data and needs to be calculated at 255 to properly display.

Fragment example

```
 precision mediump float;

 uniform sampler2D background;
 uniform sampler2D frame;
 uniform sampler2D mask;


 uniform float texWidth;
 uniform float texHeight;


 void main(void) {
vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(texWidth,texHeight);
vec2 frameuv = texCoord * vec2(texWidth, texHeight) / vec2(200.0, 200.0);

vec4 texel0 = texture2D(background, texCoord);
vec4 frameTex = texture2D(frame, frameuv.xy);
vec4 maskTex = texture2D(mask, frameuv.xy);

gl_FragColor = mix(texel0, frameTex, step(frameuv.x, 1.0) * step(frameuv.y, 1.0) * maskTex.a * 255.);

 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/danrossi303/82tpoy94/3/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scale video texture with mask over image texture background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136187/scale-video-texture-with-mask-over-image-texture-background)

Comment: unfortunately no. I need to be able to move the scaled video and it's mask to either corners of the viewport. I have moved back to doing a flipY video textures need in the textcoords. So because of this it displays in the top left corner for now.